# Empty value imputation in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, feature-engineering

I am trying to impute empty values by NA and the code is working fine using only Scala but when I am running the code in Spark then it is not working

```
/* first way:- */
def blankImputation(input: String): String = {
    val pattern2 =  """(^.*?,,+.*$)""".r;
    if (pattern2.findFirstIn(input).contains(",,")) {
        return pattern2.replaceAllIn(input, ",NA,");
    }
    return input;
}

var cleaned_df = inputFile.map(blankImputation)


/* second way:- */
def blankImputation(input: String): String = {
    val pattern2 =  """(^.*?,,+.*$)""".r;
    if (input.isEmpty()) {
        return "NA";
    }
    return input;
}

var cleaned_df = inputFile.map(blankImputation)
cleaned_df.toDF().collect()
```

I expect NA instead of Empty values.

Comment: What did not worked is spark, what error do you get, how you used it can you share it?

Comment: I didn't get any error but it didn't impute the consecutive single quotes. Here is my code:- var cleaned_df = inputFile.map(blankImputation)
I am trying to take line as key and do the empty value imputation.

Comment: what is inputFile here, how do you read it ?

Comment: input file is csv, I am just reading it into rdd:-
val inputFile = sc.textFile("test/cust_details.csv")

Comment: If you have a csv file why don't you read as a csv to dataframe? as `spark.read.csv(csv).na.fill("NA")` This will replace all of your empty value as `NA`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Shankar for your effort. I could able to impute the missing values after following the below steps:- 1. I loaded the csv file into dataframe. 2. After loading into the dataframe, the empty values got replaced by null so I imputed the null values using this code:

```scala
val nullReplacer = udf((x: String) => { if (x == null) "N" else x })
```